# What is MongoDB's equivalent to RethinkDB's r.row?

Tags: mongodb, rethinkdb

The project I am working on uses MongoDB, but I usually use RethinkDB. I am trying to write an operation that will take the current value of a document's property and subtract 1 from it. In reQL this would be `r.db('db').table('table').get('documentId').update({propToUpdate: r.row('propToUpdate').sub(1)})`. How can I preform the same function in MongoDB?

Comment: In MongoDB you would probably just send the document selection criteria within an `update()` and use [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) if that is what you mean? Probably better to show the "MongoDB" people your "MongoDB" document and what you want to happen rather than *"I do this with rethink(sic)"* since they would be more likely to understand the former approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use $inc operator:

```
db.products.update(
   { sku: "abc123" },
   { $inc: { quantity: -1} }
);
```

As an example extract from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

Where "db" is the database, (e.g. use myDatabase), "products" is the name of the collection you want to query, "sku" is the field you are querying and "quantity" is the field you want to increment/decrement.

Comment: This does solve my problem (I was actually defining req.query.prizeId wrong earlier in case you saw the comment I deleted). However I would still really like to know how to reference the currently visited document in a MongoDB query.